# References for Texas Holdem

Tags: references, monte-carlo, games

Does anybody know any good papers or software that use Monte Carlo techniques to estimate the probability of certain hands or winning/losing a hand in Texas Holdem?

Ideally I'd like to have some probability estimates that condition on the hand the first person is currently holding, the size of the table, the round of betting, maybe even betting patterns, etc. This is nontrivial to program, so I figure I'd ask around first.